# What's this vocal piece in the beginning of episode 18?

Tags: music, cowboy-bebop

I'm on episode 18 of *Cowboy Bebop*, and I noticed vocal background music sung by a male singer that seemed rather classical in style at the beginning, when there is a montage of Faye at a horserace.

What is the title of this piece? Is it something classical music, or is it an original soundtrack-specific composition? The Wikia for the episode doesn't seem to give me anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [lyrics](http://www.elyrics.net/read/c/cowboy-bebop-lyrics/adieu-lyrics.html) are clearly from the song  [**Adieu**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ws8X31TTB5E) (lyric: Brian Richy, singer: Emily Bindiger):

> Been a fool, been a clown 
>   Lost my way from up and down 
>   And I know, yes, I know 
>   And I see in your eyes that you really weren't surprised at me 
>   At all 
>   Not at all 
>   And I know by your smile 
>   It's you

However the singer in episode 18 is male and I haven't managed to find who he is yet.

Comment: The episode 18 is the alternate version by the Seatbelts http://www.rfblues.net/Seatbelts/u.htm